# How to efficiently store 16 bit ints in a redis list

Tags: python, redis

We need to feed 16-bit integer data to a Redis (circular) list.

There is a lot of data so we don't want to send more than the 16-bit data over the network, nor store more than we need in memory on the Redis server.

I'm fairly new to Redis and don't have all a full grasp of all performance characteristics and features yet.

How do I ensure I'm being memory/bandwidth-efficient with the 16-bit ints. I don't see an obvious way in the docs to declare a data type.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be ([binary compatible](https://redis.io/topics/data-types)) strings. Data that needs to be packed should be serialized to a binary form (for example, `numpy.tobytes(...)` and passed as a string type. The python API for redis will accept a byte array just fine.

To be efficient with lots of samples we have packed blocks of data into each binary string we add to the Redis list.